# How to startup Spring Boot service AND run startup script

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, jib

I am using JHipster to create springboot application and I think it uses JIB to create the docker container. Everything works fine, but what about doing a startup script or running additional stuff. In my case i need to startup an apt installed service

```
CMD service pcscd start
```

If i put just in image this will not happen on startup. When I add it to the POD definition in Kubernetes it wipes out the springboot application startup and just exits like all I wanted to do was run the command. How do I run a startup script that will first startup my pcscd service and THEN startup the spring boot app?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to run multiple commands, primarily using a shell:

1. Run the commands using the "shell form" of `ENTRYPOINT`. (However, the `Dockerfile` reference prefers the "exec form" below.) Behind the scene, this "shell form" actually runs a shell binary (like `/bin/sh`) and let the shell interpret the "script" (here, `echo one && echo two`).

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
ENTRYPOINT echo one && echo two
```

2. Run the commands using the "exec form" of `ENTRYPOINT`. In this case, the shell binary is invoked directly.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo one && echo two"]
```

3. If the commands become complex, consider putting them in a file. Not really different from above in that now the shell binary (as indicated by `#/bin/sh` at the top of the file below) interprets what is inside the script file.

```
echo -e '#/bin/sh'"\necho one && echo two" > my-entrypoint.sh
```

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
COPY my-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /my-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /my-entrypoint.sh
```

4. Like above, but use the "exec form".

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/my-entrypoint.sh"]
```

(FYI, you can combine using `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, but I won't go into that, since for executing multiple commands, often `ENTRYPOINT` would be enough. You can check the `Dockerfile` reference to learn how `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` interact.)

For Jib, you can use `<container><entrypoint>` / `container.entrypoint` to customize your image entrypoint. (Check the [Maven](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#extended-usage) and [Gradle](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#extended-usage) references.) And you can use the `<extraDirectories>` feature ([Maven](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image) / [Gradle](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image)) to supply arbitrary files including shell scripts. Moreover, `<extraDirectories>` allows using `<permissions>` to give, for example, executable bits to shell scripts.

Also note that the default Java base images Jib uses does not have the `/bin/sh` binary (a shell), so you will have to use a different base image that has a shell.

Lastly, note that I'm merely answering how to achieve running multiple commands for a container image. This doesn't necessarily be an ideal way to run a service in a robust and resilient way on Kubernetes (or any production environment).

Comment: Ok is there an entrypoint.sh generated in src/main/jib/entrypoint.sh with jhipster?